# On iOS6, could my App share the account with integration Facebook account in settings?

Tags: ios6, single-sign-on, facebook-ios-sdk

As we know iOS 6 integrate Facebook, just as twitter. And we can login Facebook in settings and then post photo directly.
I follow by https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login-with-facebook-using-ios-sdk/ to create my app for testing with Facebook SDK 3.0.8.
After I login in Facebook on iOS6 settings, when I open my test app and login to Facebook, it still ask me to input my account/password.

So my question is: Could my App share the account with iOS6 integration Facebook account?

I mean: After I login Facebook in settings, could I don't need to input name/password again when I open my app and login facebook?

Answer (score 3):

Support for the Facebook integration in iOS 6 is now available in the FacebookSDK (version 3.1).

Answer (score 2):

In https://developers.facebook.com/ios/ say "We will be adding support for the much anticipated iOS 6 integration to the SDK in the **coming weeks**.". So the integration with the ACAccountStore is not implement yet. That's why your app ask the info again.

If you want to connect with the info stored in the iPhone setting, you have to use the Accounts.framework and Social.framework in the iOS 6 instead Facebook SDK